# Laravel Eloquent find 1-many with mutator

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to picture this. I have two models.

```
class author extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'authors';
    public function getAuthorBioAttribute ($value)
    {
        // when we ask for author::find(1);
        // we will get an author, but we want
        // to mutate the biography of the author
        // based on what the author's book
        // titles are.
    }

    public function books () {
        return $this->hasMany('Book');
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is look up all the author's books and then alter the biographical description of the author based on the kind of books that were written. When we call this model, pulling it in by the primary id, I'll have the adjusted bio description. However, I'm not sure how to do this with Eloquent.

The `books` table contains a foreign key to the primary key of the `authors` table. What is the best way to perform this mutation? Can I just call the books method like `$this->books()` and get an array of the books based on the foreign key?

**EDIT:**

More illustration. What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
class author extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'authors';
    // Actually an accessor
    public function getAuthorBioAttribute ($value)
    {
        //say $value contains "This string"
        $books = $this->books();
        // $books now has a collection of each book object
        foreach ($books as $book) {

            if ($book->category == 'gardening')
                str_replace($value, "string", $book->category);

        }
    }

    public function books () {
        return $this->hasMany('Book');
    }
}
```

And then in my controller I'd like to use as such

```
public function authorBiography ($id) {

    $author_stuff = author::find($id);

    print_r($author_stuff->authorbio);
    // say that specific author had written some books about gardening
    // Output:
    // "This gardening"
}
```

Comment: It's unclear of what you're asking, so show example usage you need.

Comment: Added illustration. I'm trying to use the books by the author to alter the author's bio string.

Comment: Then you can use accessor (aka get mutator) as @Marcin suggested. I don't think you need anything else here.

Comment: Thanks! The eloquent docs seem sparse and I read them through but it wasn't clicking. I'm just trying to picture how exact I'm getting the author's books in the first place to use with my accessor (the mystery for me is at `foreach ($books...` how do I get those books at all?

Comment: Like in @Marcin's answer - `$this->books` it's utilizing dynamic properties http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#dynamic-properties. Otherwise you can use `$this->books()->get()`, it will be pretty much the same.

Comment: From the docs "Eloquent will automatically load the relationship for you" Thus by declaring the relation, the data will be loaded by into a dynamic property? That's my last question, thanks again!

Comment: Eloquent uses `__get` magic method, so calling `->books` works like a property, but of course it is not real property of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I think you want to create accessor and not mutator. You can access books items in foreach loop:

```
public function getAuthorBioAttribute($value)
{       
    foreach ($this->books as $book) {
       echo $book->category;  
    }
    return "something";
}
```

Probably there are other options to do it depending on your implementation and database structure. You can get rather number of books the author wrote the most and not books themselves (if it's not necessary), you could also store in authors table also type of book he most often writes.

Comment: So just by having a `public function books () { return $this->hasMany('Book'); }`it will populate a $this->books property with the specific author's books, such as when invoking ::find()?

Comment: @dirtymikeandtheboys `books` are not property here, they are relation, but when using in loop you will be able to get all books data for given author and display any string you want using accessor

Comment: If it is not a property, then in your example, is it more like `foreach ($this->books() ...)`?